# Flyway: prefix for Java migrations

Tags: java, flyway

I have a composite JAR with SQL + Java migrations. For backward compatibility I have to distinguish between a new installation and an update. I use prefixes "I" (new installation) and "V" (update):

```
configuration.sqlMigrationPrefix("I");
```

This works fine for SQL migrations, but for a Java migration class `I1_1__test.class` I get the error:

> org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid JDBC migration class name: db.migration.test.I1_1__test=> ensure it starts with V or R, or implement org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.MigrationInfoProvider for non-default naming

In the [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/hooks), there is a mention of a possibility to implement my own `MigrationResolver` coupled with a custom `MigrationExecutor`.

The problem is, I still need to keep the `SqlMigrationResolver` active, and I find very exhausting to re-implement both strategies (SQL and Java) almost from scratch just because of this.

Is there a better and simpler way?

PS: there is [an old pull request](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1130), unfortunately not merged, for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

One way, how to achieve this with no coding whatsoever, would be to put different types of migrations onto different classpath locations:

```
src/main/
    /java/
        /my/comp/db/migration/
            /install/
                V1_1__Test1.java
            /update/
                V1_2__Test2.java 
    /resources/
        /my/comp/db/migration/
            /install/
                V1.1__Test1.sql
            /update/
                V1.2__Test2.sql
```

And then set the configuration:

```
Configuration config = Flyway.configure();
...

if (isInstall())  {
    config.locations("classpath:my/comp/db/migration/install");
} else {
    config.locations("classpath:my/comp/db/migration/update");
}
```

For consistence, I would recommend to treat both SQL and Java migrations in the same manner, but you can keep the prefix-based control as well:

```
...
src/main/resources/my/comp/db/migration/sql/
    I1.1__Test1.sql
    V1.2__Test2.sql

...
if (isInstall())  {
    config.locations(
        "classpath:my/comp/db/migration/sql",
        "classpath:my/comp/db/migration/install");
    config.sqlMigrationPrefix("I");
} else {
    config.locations(
        "classpath:my/comp/db/migration/sql",
        "classpath:my/comp/db/migration/update");
    //config.sqlMigrationPrefix("V"); -- this is default
}
```